# Camera Intent vs Activity/Fragment

Tags: android

I'm to the point in my app where I am ready to implement the camera. I've used the intent method before and there is a noticeable delay when launching the phones default camera activity.

I thought I'd take a look at baking the camera into a fragment but looks like it's not exactly a trivial task, especially with Camera and Camera2 and keeping backwards comparability in mind.

Is there a significant performance increase in creating my own camera fragment within my app that would make the effort worth while? I'll be taking a lot of pictures and then uploading them via JCIFS on background threads which means I'll be calling the default camera activity via intent quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a significant performance increase in creating my own camera fragment within my app that would make the effort worth while?

Performance? Marginally, at best.

However, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations [are notoriously buggy](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html). Relying upon them is unrealistic.

My general recommendation is:

- If taking photos is a "nice to have" capability for your app, such that if `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not work reliably for the user, you and the user are willing to shrug your virtual shoulders and move on, use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. An example of this would be a note-taking app, where you want to allow users to attach photos.
- If taking photos is more important than that, but it is still somewhat of a side feature of your app, try using a library for integrating with the camera, such as [mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2). Or, give the user the choice between `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and the library's camera capability, so the user can pick between a full-featured camera (that might not work) and something fairly basic from the library (but is more likely to succeed). An example of this would be an app for an insurance claims adjuster, where she needs to be able to document the claim with photos, but the point of the app is bigger than the photos.
- If taking photos is the point of your app, integrate with the APIs directly, so you can have complete control over the experience. An example of this would be Snapchat. Or [InstantFace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoHeIZDI8Dc), presumably.

Comment: Hmm... that link was an interesting read. I have a beta version of this app that we've been running for a while using the intent without issue but we are talking about scaling the usage from a handful of people to the entire company so perhaps your thoughts on reliability our worth considering. Thanks!

Comment: @ColebyConner: Your phrasing of "to the entire company" suggests an internal-use app, not one that's going to the public on the Play Store. In that case, you're probably in good shape: not only will few people have a problem, but you can more readily communicate with them. You might try your app with a few publicly-available camera apps (e.g., OpenCamera), so for those folk who *do* run into problems, you can point them to a camera app to switch to.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I was contemplating it and I think this is a good addition for version 2.0. The fact that the photos make it to the server is the important part, if the thumbnails are scaled oddly or the picture is oriented the wrong way I think we can deal with that later. I would like to open up a general version of the app to the public at some point, but that's not an immediate concern. Thanks again for your input.